# Load sqlite file into a DataFrame

Tags: sqlite, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to load an `sqlite` file into Apache Spark.

I tried like this:

```
emailsDf = spark.read.format('sqlite').load("/FileStore/tables/24ioztln1479471916526/database.sqlite")
```

But it doesn't work:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: sqlite. Please find packages at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/Third+Party+Projects
```

So what's the best way of loading an `sqlite` file?

Answer (score 3):

.format('sqlite') doesn't exists. You have to connect to sqlite using jdbc.

```
val df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(
  Map(
    "url" -> "jdbc:sqlite:/FileStore/tables/24ioztln1479471916526/database.sqlite",
    "dbtable" -> "select * from your_table")).load()
```

When you run your application you must have sqlite-jdbc-X.jar in your classpath with the suitable version you're using.

Answer (score 1):

I would export the database to a CSV file with [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/):

1. `Open Database` button
2. Select your database file
3. `File →  Export → Table(s) as CSV file`, default values should be fine

Then use [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) to load the CSV file(s) into a Spark dataframe (see the link for examples).

Otherwise, you could also try to connect with JDBC to a hosted instance of your database.